# How to re-sort after initial layout sort in D3?

Tags: javascript, sorting, d3.js

I have an initial layout as follows:

```
var filteredPartition = d3.layout.partition().sort(function (a, b) { return d3.ascending(a.fileType, b.fileType); })
    .sort(function (a, b) { return d3.descending(a.dateAccessed, b.dateAccessed); })
    .value(function (d) { return d.size; })
    .children(function (d) { /*some code that only adds specific children*/ }
```

So the layout sorts initially by fileType and then by dateAccessed and only has specific children added.

I then allow for adding in children by providing a scroll so I have an update function which now transitions to a new layout (and the application uses this layout from this point forward):

```
partition = d3.layout.partition().sort(function (a, b) { return d3.ascending(a.fileType, b.filetype); }).sort(function (a, b) { return d3.descending(a.name, b.name); })
              .children(function (d) { /* add in new children */ })
                .value(function (d) { return d.size; });
```

I want to allow a user to select a "sort by" and "then sort by" option, but I have two issues:

1. I don't want to re-calculate the layout each time if a user selects a new sort combination as I am sure this will have an impact on performance - how would I re-sort on the existing "partition" layout variable?
2. I am finding that if I attempt to re-sort (by sorting as a new layout as I don't know how to otherwise at the moment) that it doesn't change much - is there an interference from the default sort? Should I reset the sort to null and then re-sort?

Thanks so much!

Comment: You'll have to rerun the layout when changing the sorting function. Not sure what you mean with your second question, could you provide an example?

Comment: Hi @LarsKotthoff, not the answer I was hoping for because it becomes quite slow re-sorting the layout each time, but I guess it has to do. What I meant was, seeing as though the default sort is descending value, found here: https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Partition-Layout, that could it be sorting by that first then mine i.e. interfering with the sort? Do you need to set it to null and then sort? Thanks!

Comment: You shouldn't need to do that.

Comment: Ok thanks! Will have a look what is happening then.